# Pytorch Matrix Multiplication Error while extracting features from VGG Model

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement Neural Style Transfer Algorithm. I am using the pretrained VGG model in Pytorch. In the given Code below, i tried to extract particular layers from the model so that i can pass my image through them. But i keep getting an error on `x=layer(x)`

```
def get_features(img,model):
  layers= {
    '0': 'conv1_1',
    '5': 'conv2_1',
    '10': 'conv3_1',
    '19': 'conv4_1',
    '21': 'conv4_2',
    '28': 'conv5_1'
  }

  x=img

  Features={}
  for name,layer in model._modules.items():
    x=layer(x)
    if name in layers:
      
      Features[layers[name]]=x

  return Features
```

Here is the snapshot of the Full Error.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [118], in <module>
----> 1 content_f=get_features(content_p,vgg)

Input In [117], in get_features(img, model)
     13 Features={}
     14 for name,layer in model._modules.items():
---> 15   X=layer(x)
     16   if name in layers:
     18     Features[layers[name]]=X

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1102, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1098 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1099 # this function, and just call forward.
   1100 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py:141, in Sequential.forward(self, input)
    139 def forward(self, input):
    140     for module in self:
--> 141         input = module(input)
    142     return input

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1102, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1098 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1099 # this function, and just call forward.
   1100 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py:103, in Linear.forward(self, input)
    102 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 103     return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:1848, in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1846 if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
   1847     return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848 return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (3006x500 and 25088x4096)
```

What i am doing wrong here?

P.S: The image has been pre processed, Having a shape of `torch.Size([1, 3, 1002, 500])`

Any Help would be much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The PyTorch torch vision library has a very intuitive VGG_16 model you can extract the features from:

```
import torch, torchvision as tv
model = tv.models.vgg16()
img_batch = torch.randn([1,3,512,512])

feature_extractor = model.features
Features=[]
x = img_batch.clone()
for name,layer in feature_extractor._modules.items():
   x=layer(x)
   if type(layer) is torch.nn.Conv2d:
      Features.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your piece of code worked too, but all i needed to change in my code was typecast 'name' as string while searching it up in the layers dictionary.